Configure Apache to serve a path directly, while proxying everything else to /
I want Apache to serve the /filemanager path directly, while proxying everything else to /.
I tried to use this configuration, but I'm always redirected to /
<Location /filemanager>
    ProxyPass !
</Location>

<Location />
    ProxyPass http://test.com:7777/
    ProxyPassReverse http://test.com:7777/
</Location>

If I remove the second location block, /filemanager brings me to the filesystem, which is what I want.
Thank you for any help.
